# Как с помощью javascript получить исходный код текущией страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Необходимо записать в переменную  исходный код страницы(Dom) в качестве строки.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно это реализовать?

Comment: `document.documentElement.outerHTML`? Но к чему такие извращения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сам исходный код проще всего получить непосредственно с сервера(или из кеша):
*К сожалению, в сниппете такое работать не будет.*

```
  fetch(location.href)
    .then(res => res.text())
    .then(res => console.log(res));
```

---

Если интересует уже разобранный DOM, то есть разные способы получить это.

Без `<html>`:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML         
document.documentElement.innerHTML
```

С `html`(но без `<!doctype`):

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML         
document.documentElement.outerHTML
```

Полностью:

```js
let html = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document);
console.log(html);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head><title>Test</title></head>
  <body>
    <h2>Hello, world</h2>
  </body>
</html>
<script>let a = 2;</script>
```

Как можно заметить, последний `<script>` оказался внутри `body`, т.е. мы получаем результат после разбора исходного кода браузера.

Answer (score 0):

Именно исходный код получить невозможно.

Есть несколько способов получить результат парсинга исходного кода в виде строки.

```js
alert(document.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

```html
<p><div></div></p>
```

Обрати внимание на

```
<p></p><div></div><p></p>
```

вместо

```
<p><div></div></p>
```